# How can I scale a locator's coordinate within an image?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, locator

How can I use the `Scaled` feature and modify the `Appearance` of the `Locator` within `Manipulate`? That is, I would like `mouse` to have the scaled coordinate of `Locator` not its pixel coordinate. From the documentation, it is clear how to do this for `Dynamic` but not for `Manipulate`.

```
heart = Image[
   Graphics[Text[Style["\[HeartSuit]", 42, Red]], Background -> None]];
couple = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Couple"}];

Manipulate[
 Multicolumn[{ImageCompose[couple, {2 heart, 0.5}, mouse], mouse}],
 {{mouse, Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe not use `Scaled` at all. Just divide `mouse` by `ImageDimensions`. Or use `Dynamic` as you said, `Manipulate` is pretty limited, no need to push it.

Comment: You could try with: `DynamicModule[{x = {0, .5}}, Column[{
   Graphics[{     
     FaceForm@None, EdgeForm@Thick, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 30}],
     Locator[      Dynamic[Scaled@x, (x = MousePosition["GraphicsScaled"]) &]]     }, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200],   Dynamic@Scaled@x   }  ] ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As swish suggests in a comment, a simple solution is to just divide by the image size.

```
heart = 
  Image[Graphics[Text[Style["\[HeartSuit]", 48, Red]], Background -> None]];
couple = ImageAdjust[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Couple"}], {0, 0.75, 0.7}]

With[{size = ImageDimensions[couple]},
  Manipulate[
    Column[
      {Magnify[ImageCompose[couple, 2 heart, mouse], 3],
       mouse/size},
      Center],
   {{mouse, size/2.}, Locator, Appearance -> None}]]
```

[image: couple]